# Jetty Application Server 9.3.16 linux context file based deployment

Tags: linux, deployment, jetty

i have a problem and i doesn't see the solution.

I have a jetty application server running under slepos. It starts and the webapps folder contains a context file xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
                       "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.quickstart.QuickStartWebApp">    
<Set name="contextPath"><Property name="noti_1.0.0.localbuild"/>/</Set>
<Set name="war">/programs/noti/noti_1.0.0.localbuild</Set>
<Set name="tempDirectory">/programs/jetty_applicationserver/temp/noti1.0.0.localbuild</Set>
<Set name="autoPreconfigure">true</Set>
<Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
    <Arg>nothing.jar</Arg>
</Call>
```

This doesn't causes in deployment errors but jetty shows on the root...

```
/ ---> o.e.j.q.QuickStartWebApp@18486a3{/,file:///programs/noti/noti_1.0.0.localbuild/,UNAVAILABLE}{/programs/noti/noti_1.0.0.localbuild} [failed]
```

Can you help me? I think this isn't a big thing!

I tryed to deploy it unziped and the folder "/programs/noti/noti_1.0.0.localbuild" exist and is filled which the content of the maven generaded "noti_1.0.0.localbuild.war"

The exact same xml context description file works on windows (except the path from c:\programs to /programs). It is excatly the same!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks possibly like a permissions issue. Does your Jetty process have access to read from that directory? I've not been able to replicate this.

Comment: HI, thank you for your response! That comes to my mind too, but the log schows ---"INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named notification.ws.price.ws.WebAppApplicationClass, at the servlet mapping /*, with the Application class of the same name."---

Comment: That shows to me that the file WebAppApplicationClass inside the unziped folder under "/programs/noti/noti_1.0.0.localbuild" is found!

Comment: What does your `quickstart-web.xml` contain (found in your webapp)?